# html email spacing between sections

Tags: html, email, space

I was looking quite a bit on here for an answer, but didn't find anything. 
I've got some strange spacing/ gaps between different sections of my email. I checked for any padding, margins, spacing or borders but I couldn't fix the issue.

I don't really know what else to do..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqSgX.jpg

Here's the whole code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>VG Divendoor - mojaskrina.sk</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        /*////// RESET STYLES //////*/
        body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
        table{border-collapse:collapse;}
        img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0;}

        /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */
        img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */

        /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES //////*/
        .flexibleContainerCell{padding-top:10px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}
        .flexibleImage{height:auto;}
        .bottomShim{padding-bottom:20px;}
        .imageContent, .imageContentLast{padding-bottom:20px;}
        .nestedContainerCell{padding-top:20px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}

        /*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/
        body, #bodyTable{background-color:#6c6c6c;}
        #bodyCell{padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:40px;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; text-align:Left;}
        .textContent, .textContentLast{color:#404040; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:16px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left; padding-bottom: 0px;}
        .textContent a, .textContentLast a{color:#2C9AB7; text-decoration:underline;}
        .nestedContainer{background-color:#E5E5E5; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}

        /*////// MOBILE STYLES //////*/
        @media only screen and (max-width: 680px){          
            /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Force iOS Mail to render the email at full width. */

            /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES //////*/
            /*
                CSS selectors are written in attribute
                selector format to prevent Yahoo Mail
                from rendering media query styles on
                desktop.
            */
            table[id="emailBody"], table[class="flexibleContainer"]{width:100% !important;}

            /*
                The following style rule makes any
                image classed with 'flexibleImage'
                fluid when the query activates.
                Make sure you add an inline max-width
                to those images to prevent them
                from blowing out. 
            */
            img[class="flexibleImage"]{height:auto !important; width:100% !important;}

            /*
                Make buttons in the email span the
                full width of their container, allowing
                for left- or right-handed ease of use.
            */
            table[class="emailButton"]{width:100% !important;}
            td[class="buttonContent"]{padding:0 !important;}
            td[class="buttonContent"] a{padding:15px !important;}

            td[class="textContentLast"], td[class="imageContentLast"]{padding-top:20px !important;}

            /*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/
            td[id="bodyCell"]{padding-top:10px !important; padding-Right:10px !important; padding-Left:10px !important;}
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                    <!-- EMAIL CONTAINER // -->
                    <!--
                        The table "emailBody" is the email's container.
                        Its width can be set to 100% for a color band
                        that spans the width of the page.
                    -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailBody">


                        <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                        <!--
                            To move or duplicate any of the design patterns
                            in this email, simply move or copy the entire
                            MODULE ROW section for each content block.
                        -->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                <!--
                                    The centering table keeps the content
                                    tables centered in the emailBody table,
                                    in case its width is set to 100%.
                                -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                            <!--
                                                The flexible container has a set width
                                                that gets overridden by the media query.
                                                Most content tables within can then be
                                                given 100% widths.
                                            -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" >


                                                        <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                        <!--
                                                            The content table is the first element
                                                            that's entirely separate from the structural
                                                            framework of the email.
                                                        -->
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                 <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0d4b/achw81nuavm345cfg.jpg" alt="Mojaskrina.sk | jeden priestor - tisíc možností"></a>
                                                                  </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                  <td  background="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0563/moeszz5zt3vyn4ofg.jpg" style="padding: 20px; background-repeat: no-repeat; ">
                                                                    <h1 style="color:#5c5c5c; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: -10px;">Ďakujeme Vám za prejavený záujem o naše služby!</h1>
                                                                    <p style=" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#5c5c5c; line-height: 20px">Posielame Vám grafický návrh s cenou na vstavanú skriňu podľa požiadavky.
                                                                    Ceny sú vrátane DPH, zamerania, dopravy, montáže a aktuálnej zľavy. Cena sa spresní po zameraní. Zameranie prevedieme zvyčajne do 5 pracovných dní od objednania a zloženia zálohy, montáž 4 týždne 
                                                                    od zloženia zálohy. Pri objednávke sa skladá záloha vo výške 40% z celkovej kalkulovanej ceny, zvyšok sa platí po montáži skrine priamo technikovi, ktorý Vám zároveň odovzdá dodací list, faktúru, záručný list 
                                                                    a preberací protokol.</p>
                                                                  </td>                                                           
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width="150" >
                                                                    <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/spalne-postele/postele/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/fc30/ixe77cwhanckebcfg.jpg" alt="Postele na mieru"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                  <td width="150" >
                                                                    <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/spalne-postele/nocne-stoliky/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7a17/vqj0ebhgafvvdrwfg.jpg" alt="Nočné stolíky"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                  <td width="150" >
                                                                    <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/spalne-postele/komody/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/e12c/gm6w81oiqmcza2ufg.jpg" alt="Komody"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                  <td width="150" >
                                                                    <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/spalne-postele/vesiakove-steny/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/e7e2/juzxq7zjv6z9zs0fg.jpg" alt="Vešiakové steny"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0966/3742rgmrt7tm7drfg.jpg" alt="Profesionalita"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/f0e4/h6tmm0xha6s6leufg.jpg" alt="Spolahlivosť"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d4a4/vkpgbe2qkqpxrq4fg.jpg" alt="Tradícia"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3d46/3m1723tttcasscrfg.jpg" alt="Ceny"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6746/emxpawmymbha5ibfg.jpg" alt="Rýchlost"></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/ce5f/jy7iy61o0yr8b8ofg.jpg" alt="Záruka"></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/cd89/a18sfn2fdrcw1ozfg.jpg" alt="Servis"></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3929/aj6jwkfzo8pk8pgfg.jpg" alt="Splátky"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->

                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td><a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/divendoor/skrine-na-splatky/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0151/4jy39v9dgm3ep4tfg.jpg" alt="Nákup na splátky bez navýšenia"></td>
                                                                <td><a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/vstavane-skrine-navrhar/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/5fdb/i9a70bi9dng9jezfg.jpg" alt="Online návrh skrine"></a></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <table valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td  height="105" background="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/4ef5/l948a585o2rmxw9fg.jpg">
                                                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/vstavanesatniky.sk"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/8460/cddlbt0bx88ar8jfg.jpg" style="margin: 0 25px 0 25px; " alt="Facebook" /></a>
                                                                    <a href="http://www.mojaskrina.sk/nase-predajne/"><img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2b2c/lazrad7327m6nlafg.jpg" alt="Kontakt" /></a>
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0 50px 0 100px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; width:140px; height:90px;">
                                                                    VG Divendoor</br>
                                                                    OD CENTRUM</br>
                                                                    Zohorská 1, Bratislava</br>
                                                                    02 65 411 174</br>
                                                                    0911 48 16 58</br> 
                                                                    centrum@mojaskrina.sk</p>
                                                                    <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; width:140px; height:85px;">
                                                                    VG Divendoor</br>
                                                                    OC SARATOV</br>
                                                                    Saratovská 9, Bratislava</br>
                                                                    02 6436 0047</br>
                                                                    0914 196 095</br>
                                                                    saratov@mojaskrina.sk</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                    </table>
                    <!-- // EMAIL CONTAINER -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</body>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/jRe5D/ ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your different sections are in different `<table></table>` elements.

You should place them in `<div></div>` tags instead.

You could also use CSS to use relative positioning to change exactly where your blocks are.

Hope this help

**EDIT**

Paste this in place of your current code where the error exists:

```
        <tr>
            <td  background="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0563/moeszz5zt3vyn4ofg.jpg"style="padding: 20px; background-repeat: no-repeat; ">
        <h1 style="color:#5c5c5c; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: -14px;">Ďakujeme Vám za prejavený záujem o naše služby!</h1>
    <p style=" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#5c5c5c;">
Posielame Vám grafický návrh s cenou na vstavanú skriňu podľa požiadavky.
            Ceny sú vrátane DPH, zamerania, dopravy, montáže a aktuálnej zľavy. Cena sa spresní po zameraní. Zameranie prevedieme zvyčajne do 5 pracovných dní od objednania
         a zloženia zálohy, montáž 4 týždne od zloženia zálohy. Pri objednávke sa skladá záloha vo výške 40% z celkovej kalkulovanej ceny, zvyšok sa platí po montáži skrine priamo technikovi, ktorý Vám zároveň odovzdá dodací list, faktúru, záručný list a preberací protokol.</p>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Glad this worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Darrell. Removing the tables just messed up the whole layout.. http://oi57.tinypic.com/244uufl.jpg I tried to use CSS as you mentioned, but I cannot address the table elements with ID or class. The CSS just doesn't have any effect. But it might be just my lack of knowledge with tables.. how would you code the CSS exactly? Cheers

Comment: check my edit @Mike That will fix  your problem. Please select mine as having answered your question

Comment: ye, I tried to remove that, but with no effect... very strange :/

Comment: These are all tips on what you should not do when coding an email.

Comment: could you clarify on which gaps you want gone then? I thought you just wanted the gaps to all be the same size so it would look nice.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to correct the email. It looks good in the browser... but when I send it (using Mozilla Thunderbird) the whole thing messes up completely. I am kind of hopeless. jsfiddle.net/28Mps/1 oi62.tinypic.com/2412d52.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a bunch of things wrong with the way your email is coded.  I posted a template on Gist for you if you'd like to use it as a template/guide...  If you use this example and rewrite your email you won't have this problem and you'll actually have created a far superior email than you currently have.

https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/727145a5d161c9475558

Comment: Thanks dcc. Could you just briefly tell me what's wrong with this one? Actually it's also a template that I just edited..

Comment: Whatever template it is, it's a very bad one.  Just to start with.. you should never use any of the following in an email: div, css padding or margin, any css properties (regardless of inline or head) that could be replaced by an html attribute, h1-h6 tags, paragraphs

Comment: Ok, so I managed to correct the email. It looks good in the browser... but when I send it (using Mozilla Thunderbird) the whole thing messes up completely. I am kind of hopeless. 
http://jsfiddle.net/28Mps/1/

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2412d52.jpg

Comment: What do you mean 'messes up completely'? In the screenshot it just looks like the images are not displaying.  Mozilla Thunderbird, as well as Microsoft Outlook do not display images by default. Typically there is a notification bar which the programs displays prompting the user whether or not they want to display images but there is no way whatsoever to display images in these clients automatically if it is set to not display them.  It's completely impossible.

Comment: ye, Thunderbird is the problem. I'll send it just normally through gmail.. works good that way. Thanks for help :)